# mySql thinks mac OSX is case sensitive

Tags: mysql, macos

In my `etc/my.cnf` file I have tried to adjust the `lower_case_table_names` variable to 2. I get the following error in the mysql error log:

> lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system
>   '/usr/local/mysql/data/' is case sensitive.  Now setting
>   lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems.

Now I assumed that Mac was case INSENSITIVE. So why does MySQL think my file system is case sensitive?

Comment: mac DEFAULTS to case insensitive, but it can run in a "sensitive" mode.

Comment: it depends on what file system you have your drives set to. Some are case insensitive, some case sensitive, and the default is case preserving, case insensitive.

Comment: How do I then set my drive to case insensitive?

Comment: Maybe you can't. See the dupe target this was closed to. I improved Praveen's answer. Maybe it is a better roadmap to understanding now. There is the doc comment *However, OS X also supports UFS volumes, which are case sensitive just as on any Unix*